# Resource is not exhausted, why is YARN waiting for resources

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I have a 3 node cluster (1 Resource Manager, 2 Node Managers 32GB each).
I just follow the instructions from the apache flink doc [YARN Setup](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html) when I started the YARN session, Flink run reports not enough resource to start AM. Then I stoped the YARN session, Flink run worked.

Application is Activated, waiting for resources to be assigned for AM. Last Node which was processed for the application : flink02.myminda.com:39826 ( Partition : [], Total resource : , Available resource :  ). Details : AM Partition =  ; Partition Resource =  ; Queue's Absolute capacity = 100.0 % ; Queue's Absolute used capacity = 18.333334 % ; Queue's Absolute max capacity = 100.0 % ;

`yarn-site.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
            <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
            <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
            <value>flink01</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>


    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
            <value>30720</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>30720</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>1024</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
            <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.log.aggregation-enable</name>
            <value>false</value>
    </property>


</configuration>
```

```
mapred-site.xml
```

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
        <value>10240</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx8192m</value>
    </property>



    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
        <value>10240</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx8192m</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
        <value>10240</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx8192m</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on when you provide no details about how YARN was setup.  `yarn-site.xml` and your scheduler's config would be a start.

Comment: I’ll post files later.Thank you.

Comment: @tk421 Could you please show me some clues?

Comment: How much memory for each NodeManager?

Comment: @tk421 32G for each node

Comment: What are you trying to run via Flink?  How many nodes?  Anything useful in any of the Hadoop YARN logs (Resource Manager, Node Managers)?

Comment: I have 3 nodes( 1 master and two nodes). I just follow the instructions from the apache flink  doc. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html. when I started yarn session, flink run reports not enough resource to start AM. Then I stoped the yarn session, flink run worked.

Comment: It looks like your livelocked.  What is your Flink command?  Maybe you're requesting more than this cluster can provide.

Comment: Perhaps I found the reason. I didn't put flink directory to each node.

Comment: It's working now?